# How get the header of the site?

Tags: python, header

I have this link:
http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/mper.1991.88667

How can I get the header of it with python and find `arnumber=88667` within?
That means: only get http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=88667
(and not all of the site or other)
and then find arnumber=88667.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option (without requests or mechanize):

```
import urllib2

url_path = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/mper.1991.88667"
urllib2.urlparse.parse_qs(urllib2.urlopen(url_path).url)["arnumber"][0]
>>> '88667'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to use python's [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) and [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) modules. If retrieving just the article number is all that you want, there is no need for an external library or framework like `requests`. Here's the code:

```
import urllib2
from urlparse import parse_qs, urlsplit

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/mper.1991.88667')
url = response.url
print url       # http://ieeexplore.ieee.org:80/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=88667

article = parse_qs(urlsplit(url).query)['arnumber'][0]
print article   # 88667
```

This code might seem a little long and wordy, however, this should help you to see what it actually does.

If you need to do more advanced stuff later on like simulate a browser (navigating through a series of pages, accepting cookies, etc.), I can recommend [`mechanize`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/). This is a very powerful library and might be to much if you only want to retrieve the article number. How to get the arnumber string is given in the example code below:

```
from mechanize import Browser
from urlparse import parse_qs, urlsplit

br = Browser()
response = br.open('http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/mper.1991.88667')

url = response.geturl()
print url       # http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=88667

article = parse_qs(urlsplit(url).query)['arnumber'][0]
print article   # 88667
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requests` and the `urlparse` library:

```
import requests
from urlparse import parse_qs, urlsplit

r = requests.get('http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/mper.1991.88667')
print parse_qs(urlsplit(r.url).query)['arnumber'][0]
```

Although it does look like you could just do:

```
print 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/mper.1991.88667'.rpartition('.')[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install requests

import requests
from urlparse import parse_qs, urlsplit

r = requests.get("http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/mper.1991.88667")
url = r.url
get_parameter = parse_qs(urlsplit(url).query)['arnumber'][0]
```

More information can be found in the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and the [urlparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).